# Which JS framework used for this site?

Tags: jquery-mobile

Can anyone tell which Javascript framework is being used for http://iphone.paulmillersubaru.com/index.htm#index_p_2Ehtm

Is this based on jquerymobile.com or is it using some other framework?

Thanks,

Jatinder Thind

Comment: use the source (ctrl-u in FF/chrome)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That site also includes [`jQTouch`](http://www.jqtouch.com/). That provides animations.

Answer (score 0):

If I view page source and search for javascript I can see all the libraries it uses.  So can you:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.dealer.com/v8/global/js/jquery/jquery-1.4.1.mod.pack.js?1319813505000"></script>
```

Looks like jQuery to me.

Comment: I know is uses jQuery but is it using Jquery Mobile as well? I basically want to replicate that "slide" functionality. For example, click on "Contact Us", the page loads in background and the current page slides to left and new page slides in.

Comment: I told you how to look for yourself.  Try it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is using jquery framework.

Just RightClick and View Page Source.

Search for Jquery. You will find it :)

Comment: But is it using "Jquery Mobile Framework"?

Comment: No, its not jquery mobile. Its the jquery framework.

Answer (score 0):

Its not using jQuery mobile, It's using [bootstrap.js](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) and some other js files. As others mentioned its really not to difficult to see exactly which js files the site is using, just view the source or open it up in a debugger ([firebug](https://getfirebug.com/), [web inspector](http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/WebInspector) [etc](http://www.opera.com/dragonfly/)).